# Rabbitmq: how worker can "ignore" a message and let an other worker treating it

Tags: rabbitmq

Here's my current architecture

I have a bunch of IoT devices, that connects through raw duplex persistent TCP to 1 instances of my "worker" that is connected to a RabbitMQ Queue

My publisher publishes some messages that look like that

```
{
   "iot_device_name" : "A",
   "command" : "reboot"
}
```

The worker is then able to map the `iot_device_name` to the TCP socket.

All is working nice, but if we want to add HA and to scale out a bit, it would be better to have 4 instances of the worker. Load balancing the TCP question is not a problem (with HaProxy or Nginx).

Now the problem is on how to split the load on the Queue part, as the list of IoT devices handled by a worker is dynamic (i.e a device could disconnect and reconnect to an other worker)

**So is there a way for a worker to say: "Hmmm no I can't treat this message because I don't know this device, give me an other" so that an other worker can then take it and handle it ?**

Other information that may be of help:

- the workers are all in the same network, that is also the same than the publisher
- the numbers of workers is not dynamic and even if we extrapolate the number of devices for the next years, 8 workers would takes us VERY FAR, as it simply route message/transcode messages, so their cpu load is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your architecture correctly, you have commands sent to your publisher on one side, which are pushed into rabbitmq.
On the consumer side, you have multiple workers, to which the messages are dispatched, and each worker has a bunch of devices connected to it.

If indeed this is your architecture, I'd propose the following for your rabbitmq configuration:

- use a direct exchange
- each worker has it's own queue (exclusive), and manages the bindings between the exchange and its queue dynamically:

  - each time a device connects to a worker, that worker adds a binding between its queue and the exchange with as routing key the identifier for the device
  - each time a worker detects that a device is not connected to it anymore, he removes the related binding from the rabbitmq configuration
- related to the detection of disconnected devices, I'd expect it common that it's upon receiving a command to push to the device that a worker realize the device isn't connected to it anymore, in such cases in addition to adapting the bindings, the worker would republish the message to the same exchange with the same routing key, so that it can have another shot at being consumed by the proper worker
- I'd also consider configuring a TTL on the queues, no point in consuming a message that's too old
- The publisher will of course also need to alter the message, including the intended device identification as routing key

I hope the proposal here makes sense, there are a few other cases to be considered: alternate exchange to make sure we don't lose requests if there is a (short) period when the device hasn't reconnected to a worker and we get a command for it anyway, adding a property to a message republished to ensure we do not add an infinite loop in the system, ... but what is indicated above should be a reasonable starting point to achieve your goal

Comment: your answer seems like what I was looking for :), just some little questions:
1. is it ok to have potentially 10k routing key ? (max 50k)
2. if one of my worker dies, what will happen ?

Comment: Sure, what's the question and which precisions would you like?

Comment: sorry I pressed enter too fast, I've edited my comment.

Comment: Haven't had cases with that many bindings, I'd expect if your rabbitmq has been provided with enough ressources (number of open files, memory, ...) it would hold, but this needs to be tested.

Comment: oh I was thinking , would it be possible (I'm new to rabbitmq) to have an exchange, linked to one queue per worker, in fanout,  so that all messages to all workers queue ,  and they just consume without doing anything when it's a worker not related to them ? so that we don't have to put a lot of binding, and if a worker dies, the IoT device will reconnect to an other worker, that will now be able to treat its messages ?

Comment: Regarding the death of a worker, you can probably handle it by defining a dead letter exchange (and through that possibly reinjecting the messages). But that would probably mean you wouldn't be able to configure the queue as exclusive.

Comment: If you're game having your workers throwing messages if they can't handle it, it would indeed work just fine with a fanout exchange and each worker having it's own queue bound to it

Comment: ok I guess I will go with that first then, and I will accept your answer as it works.